# Trying to setup Environment Variable for Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, environment-variables

I'm suppose to setup the Environment Variable, so I can compile Visual Basic files in the Command Prompt.

So I go to System variables create a New Variable, named 'VisualBasic', but I'm not sure what root to use. Below are a couple, but non of them work. Where can is find the right folder or is my process wrong?

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\.NET SDK\v2.9\bin

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VB\Bin

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VB\Bin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to add those paths to the already existing environmet variable `Path` that already exists. If you create a new environment variable `VisualBasic` that is not used by the command line like `Path` is.

To add a path to the PATH environment variable

1. On the **Start** menu, right-click **Computer**.
2. On the context menu, click **Properties**.
3. In the **System** dialog box, click **Advanced system settings**.
4. On the **Advanced** tab of the **System Properties** dialog box, click **Environment Variables**.
5. In the **System Variables** box of the **Environment Variables** dialog box, scroll to **Path** and select it.
6. Click the lower of the two **Edit** buttons in the dialog box.
7. In the **Edit System Variable** dialog box, scroll to the end of the string in the **Variable value** box and add a semicolon `;`.
8. Add the new path after the semicolon.
9. Click **OK** in three successive dialog boxes, and then close the **System** dialog box.

> *If Visual Studio is open when you make changes to system environment variables, it will not recognize the changes until you close and reopen it.*

Comment: I tried but has no effect. When I run: vbc test.vb, I still get the error; 
'vbc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch f

Comment: What is `vbc` (vbc.exe?) and where is it located? Do a restart of your computer after adding the location of vbc to the path.

Comment: Restarting the computer works. Now I can compile, but I get an error: 

vbc : Command line error BC2035 : Error embedding Win32 manifest: Default manifest file cannot be accessed. 

I can't find any info on it. I don't think this is going to work out. I'm just going to use visual studio from now on. thanks you for the help.

Comment: I use a batch file `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\vbc "%~dp0\RunAsAdminconsole.vb" /win32manifest:"%~dp0\RunAsAdmin.manifest" /out:"%~dp0\RunAsAdminConsole.exe" /target:exe`. It assumes all other files in same directory as batch file.